# Absolute positioned item in a flex container still gets considered as item in IE & Firefox

Tags: css, css-position, flexbox, absolute

If I have multiple elements with the property `justify-content: space-between` in a flex container and I want to absolute position one of them and remove from the flex flow, as showed here:
[image: hoped result]

This works in Chrome but not in IE and Firefox as the absolute positioned element is considered as 0 width, but still in the flex flow:
[image: bugged result]

Is there a fix to this keeping the layout as it is?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/marco_fugaro/pen/rVabBJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that all it takes is three simple steps

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g0goawpm/8/))

1). Set the left and right margin to auto on each child

```
img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

2). Set the left margin on the first child to `0`

```
img:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

3). Set the right margin on the last child to `0`

```
img:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

If you miss any of these steps it will not work properly

This works in firefox and chrome, I haven't tested it in any other browsers.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Pontiacks

Apparently you can get away with adding `margin-left: auto` to the `img:nth-child(2)`

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkLuebhm/5/)

Answer (score 2):

I have a much simpler hack to solve this particular problem.

```css
div {
  background-color: #66BB66;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
div > img:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/100">
  <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150">
</div>
```

Just change the order in the DOM. The absolutely positioned element is still positioned wherever you put it, and although flexbox still treats it like it is in the flow, its position in the flow (in the dom) causes flexbox to allocate space the same way across browsers.

I believe you could use the order property to achieve the same thing.

Comment: This one worked in my case, the other solution didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found that none of these handled my case, as I have three elements I want to have evenly spaced, and one absolutely positioned sibling. I found the trick in this case is just to add `margin-right: auto` to the first element to be evenly spaced, and `margin-left: auto` to the last element to be evenly spaced. You can check it out at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tch6y99d/